# Symfony 4 deploy project in heroku Error : Expected to find class while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not found

Tags: php, git, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to push my project to heroku,
and I have already deleted the file CacheImageListener.php

but I get this error :

> remote:        Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
>   remote:        !!
>   remote:        !!  In FileLoader.php line 166:
>   remote:        !!
>   remote:        !!    Expected to find class "App\EventListener\CacheImageListener" in file "/tmp
>   remote:        !!    /build_14476c0eb2a97654b0e3e2664c0c7a65/src/EventListener/CacheImageListene
>   remote:        !!    r.php" while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not fo
>
>   remote:        !!    und! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in /tmp/build_14476c
>
>   remote:        !!    0eb2a97654b0e3e2664c0c7a65/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resourc
>
>   remote:        !!    e "/tmp/build_14476c0eb2a97654b0e3e2664c0c7a65/config/services.yaml").
>
>   remote:        !!
>
>   remote:        !!
>
>   remote:        !!  In FileLoader.php line 163:
>   remote:        !!
>
>   remote:        !!    Expected to find class "App\EventListener\CacheImageListener" in file "/tmp
>
>   remote:        !!    /build_14476c0eb2a97654b0e3e2664c0c7a65/src/EventListener/CacheImageListene
>
>   remote:        !!    r.php" while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not fo
>   remote:        !!    und! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.
>   remote:        !!
>   remote:        !!
>   remote:        !!
>   remote:        Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
>   remote:

my composer.json :

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Did you commit your deletion of `src/EventListener/CacheImageListener.php` to your `master` branch before pushing to heroku?

Comment: Also, have you tried to [clear you heroku build cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache)?